# Troubleshooting 802.1x EAP connection

Tags: wi-fi, 2.2-froyo, motorola

I actually have observed two issues, which most likely are related:

1. When I try to connect my phone (Motorola Cliq 2; Android 2.2) to 802.1x EAP protected network then the connection attempt seems to fail ~95% of time (the connection state changes from "Connecting"--> "Disconnected"--> "Connecting" --> "Disconnected" ... till it gives up). Five percents of time I am able to establish connections successfully (the connection state changes from "Connecting"--> "Obtaining IP address"-> "Connected")
2. Another interesting thing here is that Skype still works those 95% of time when my Android thinks that it is actually offline. I can send and receive Skype messages. Albeit Browser or any other WEB application does not work. The WiFi signal is at 80% and I do not have any data plan (once I leave the WiFi range then Skype stops to work)

I am new to Android platform so maybe anyone could give me hints where to look to troubleshoot these two issues? Maybe anyone could recommend tools which can extract internal information of WiFi connection state (the phone is not rooted yet, but I would not mind to do that if I have to).

P.S. The phone works perfectly fine with my WPA2-PSK configuration at home.